# Can we use Indian Server as CDN for German Server?

Tags: cdn, digital-ocean, hetzner

My client is using Hetzner Cloud Hosting. But his most of the users are from India. So in order to improve the speed we are planning to use $5 Digital Ocean droplet (Indian Data Center) as Proxy with Caching in front of Hetzner Cloud.

Hetzner Cloud is very cheap thats why  my client does not want to switch to Digital Ocean Indian Datacenter.

Other CDN Pricing are high and his users are only from India.

Will this solution work? Will it improve download speed of images if we cache images in DO droplet (India)?

Comment: I say invest 5$ and try it.

Comment: Exact same use case. Any update on this?

Comment: WTH? Never heard of cloudflare?

Comment: I know cloudflare. But my clients don't know how to use it and teaching everyone to use it is very difficult task. That's why I asked this question.